# Retrieve the Port to which TOAD for Oracle is connecting to a particular Database

Tags: database, oracle, toad, tnsnames

I am using toad for Oracle, neither toad or oracle are my regular tools but inherit a system to give maintenance. 
The point is this, Toad connects to all the DB's that I need, but I need to get the information of each connection for documentation purpose. I saw the **tnsnames.ora** but not all the connections are there. I need, giving a connection made, to know to which port is connected. I already have the Host name and service, but I am unable to pull the database port number from **sys_context** for example.

I need this, because I cannot rely on a single machine properly configured. So, does anyone knows how to see the configuration of the current connection in Toad for Oracle??

@JustinCave I just check twice again, and it's weird. The connection is being made as a TNS name (without specifying the port) but I just checked at the TNSNames editor and the database that I'm referring to is not there. 
There are any other, network resource from it is taking the TNSName configuration besides the client's TNSNames.ora??
[image]

Comment: Normally, the port in the tnsnames file (probably 1521) is the port that the listener is running on.  That redirects the actual connection to the database to a different, random port for the actual communication.  Once the session exists, you generally can't know what port the original listener connection was made on.  Unless you know the database is configured to use the same port for everything? 
 Can you just click on the connection in Toad and see how it is configured rather than querying the database?

Comment: @JustinCave I just check twice again, and it's weird. The connection is being made as a TNS name (without specifying the port) but I just checked at the TNSNames editor and the database that I'm referring to is not there. 
There are any other, network resource from it is taking the TNSName configuration besides the client's TNSNames.ora??

Comment: Possibly.  If you go to a command line and type "tnsping TNSalias" where "TNSalias" is the TNS alias that is being used in the connection, does it resolve?  If so, it'll specify which sqlnet.ora file was used which should point you at which tnsnames.ora file was used or what other method of resolution might be used other than a tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: @JustinCave  that did it! LDAP resolved the name. 
Please, post it as an answer, so I can mark it as an answer. Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to a command line and type

```
tnsping <<TNS alias from Toad>>
```

Assuming that resolves correctly, the output will contain the sqlnet.ora file that was used.  The sqlnet.ora file, in turn, will specify which TNS resolution method(s) are being used and might contain a pointer to some other tnsnames.ora file.  I don't know how sophisticated Toad is at figuring out all the tnsnames.ora files that might be involved but I'd expect it is unaware of all the options in configuring TNS name resolution.  It may also be that your client is configured to use an Oracle Names server or an LDAP server to resolve aliases instead of or in addition to one or more tnsnames.ora files.